# Master startup cannot progress, in holding-pattern until region onlined

Tags: apache, hadoop, nosql, hbase

I've setup a Hbase cluster with two nodes and I've noticed the warning "AssignmentManager: STUCK Region-In-Transition" which is not allowing the master to startup.

- Node 1: observepreserve.corp.com (Master / Zookeeper)
- Node 2: knewshoe.corp.com (Region Server)

Why it is happeneing and how to fix it?

Under Hbase UI I can see the below message.

> b94eb458bf643b46deaf6b00998d1f95  hbase:namespace,,1542792846910.b94eb458bf643b46deaf6b00998d1f95. state=OPENING, ts=Wed Nov 21 09:39:46 UTC 2018 (PT18M9.696S ago), server=knewshoe.corp.com,16020,1542792833282

Logs:

```
2018-11-21 09:40:45,900 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-observepreserve.corp.com:2181@0x4068418f] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x167359e5ad60006 closed
2018-11-21 09:40:45,900 INFO  [ReadOnlyZKClient-observepreserve.corp.com:2181@0x4068418f-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down for session: 0x167359e5ad60006
2018-11-21 09:40:49,266 WARN  [master/observepreserve:16000:becomeActiveMaster] master.HMaster: hbase:namespace,,1542792846910.b94eb458bf643b46deaf6b00998d1f95. is NOT online; state={b94eb458bf643b46deaf6b00998d1f95 state=OPENING, ts=1542793186164, server=knewshoe.corp.com,16020,1542792833282}; ServerCrashProcedures=false. Master startup cannot progress, in holding-pattern until region onlined.
2018-11-21 09:41:46,095 WARN  [ProcExecTimeout] assignment.AssignmentManager: STUCK Region-In-Transition rit=OPENING, location=knewshoe.corp.com,16020,1542792833282, table=hbase:namespace, region=b94eb458bf643b46deaf6b00998d1f95
2018-11-21 09:41:53,267 WARN  [master/observepreserve:16000:becomeActiveMaster] master.HMaster: hbase:namespace,,1542792846910.b94eb458bf643b46deaf6b00998d1f95. is NOT online; state={b94eb458bf643b46deaf6b00998d1f95 state=OPENING, ts=1542793186164, server=knewshoe.corp.com,16020,1542792833282}; ServerCrashProcedures=false. Master startup cannot progress, in holding-pattern until region onlined.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,reinstall hbase cause this problem!
This is because old metadata was not removed,you need try to delete hbase metadata from zk
and restart hbase,all will be ok,good luck.

Comment: Hi @Matiji66 can you please explain how to delete hbase metadata from zk? I run into this problem and I have issue how to resolve it - i tried with connecting with zookeeper-client and then to execute rmr /hbase-unsecure/rs and I restarted server and it didn't help. In /hbase-unsecure/meta-region-server we do not have anything. Please assist